# Safely Using JSON with html inside of the JSON in Django Templates

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

How do you safely render JSON data in a django webapp?

On the server in django I generate JSON data and then render that JSON data in a django template. The JSON occasionally contains snippets of html. Most of the time, that's fine, however if the `</script>` tag is inside the JSON data when it is rendered, it destroys the surrounding javascript.

For example...

**On the server**, in python I'll have this:

```
template_data = {
    'my_json' : '[{"my_snippet": "<b>Happy HTML</b>"}]'
}
# pass the template data to the django template
return render_to_response('my_template.html', template_data, context_instance = c)
```

And then **in the template**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var the_json = {{my_json|safe}};
</script>
... some html ...
```

The **resulting html** works fine and looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var the_json = [{"my_snippet": "<b>Happy HTML</b>"}];
</script>
... some html ...
```

However, you run into problems when, on the server, the JSON looks like this:

```
template_data = {
    'my_json' : '[{"my_snippet": "Bad HTML</script>"}]'
}
return render_to_response('my_template.html', template_data, context_instance = c)
```

Now, when it's rendered, you'll get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var the_json = [{"my_snippet": "Bad HTML</script>"}];
</script>
... some html ...
```

The closing script tag within the JSON code is treated as closing the entire script block. All of your javascript will then break.

One possible solution is to check for `</script>` when passing the template data to the template, but I feel like there is a better way.

Comment: You could serve it as json (via AJAX) or serve it as a javascript file (then include it using a script tag).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Safely insert the JSON as a string, and then call JSON.parse on it**

Use [escapejs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) instead of safe. It is designed for outputting to JavaScript.

```
var the_json = '{{my_json|escapejs}}';
```

To get a JavaScript object you then need to call `JSON.parse` on that string. This is always preferable than dumping a JSON-encoding into your script and evaluating it directly, for security reasons.

A useful filter to get python objects directly to the client that I use is this:

```
@register.filter
def to_js(value):
    """
    To use a python variable in JS, we call json.dumps to serialize as JSON server-side and reconstruct using
    JSON.parse. The serialized string must be escaped appropriately before dumping into the client-side code.
    """
    # separators is passed to remove whitespace in output
    return mark_safe('JSON.parse("%s")' % escapejs(json.dumps(value, separators=(',', ':'))))
```

And use it like:

```
var Settings = {{ js_settings|to_js }};
```

Comment: If you do that then `the_json` becomes a string, not a javascript json object.

Comment: You could do `var the_json = JSON.parse({{my_json|escapejs}})`

Comment: I think you need to quote it, like this: `var the_json = JSON.parse('{{my_json|escapejs}}')`

Comment: The first line will simply get a string safely into your javascript. You then need to deserialize which is why I've created the filter. You should definitely use `JSON.parse` rather than hoping it parses as a legal object in any case.

Comment: Surprisingly tricky to get this nested escaping right, I couldn't quite reason my way out of it even though I fully understood the problem. Huge thanks to Andrew for (nicely) documenting the proper way to do this!